# Span of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_{p}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The matrix $A$ has as columns the vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_{p}$ hence it's a $n \times p$ matrix.
It seems that the conditions to span all $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the vectors using only positive coefficients (i.e. $v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_pv_p$, with $\alpha_i>0$) are:

1. $p > n$
2. $rank(A)=n$
3. take $n$ linear-independent vectors. At least one of the other vectors is a linear composition of the $n$ linearly independent vectors with strictly negative coefficients.

I think it's very basic and convex cones theory kicks in, but I wasn't able to find any reference.

Comment: This might be of help: [Davis54](http://www.ii.uib.no/~lennart/drgrad/Davis1954.pdf)